# Error: Compile Error: invalid ID field: op.id at line 5 column 39

Tags: class

i am trying to get opportunity list id, but its giving this error. can anyone please help me out.

```
    public class Close_Date_Updation
{
    public static void crUpdated(List<Opportunity> op)
    {  
      List <Opportunity> childRecord = [Select id,Revision_Date__c,Service_Start_Date__c,CloseDate from Opportunity where  RecordType.DeveloperName IN: 'Child_Opportunity' And Master_Opportunity__c IN: op.id ]; 
      for(Opportunity rt : childRecord){        

               rt.Service_Start_Date__c = op[0].Service_Start_Date__c - 1;
               rt.Revision_Date__c = op[0].Revision_Date__c - 1;   
               rt.CloseDate = op[0].CloseDate - 1;
               childRecord.add(rt);

       }

        insert childRecord;


   }

}
```

Comment: why the op.id is inside single quotes?

Comment: sorry that was by mistake, bt even without single cotes it's giving error--  Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found 'op.id' at line 5 column 197

Comment: try with Master_Opportunity__c = :op.id

Comment: just tell me is it possible to fetch a single id from the list of opportunity

Comment: hey op is a list.. You need to use like `Master_Opportunity__c IN : op`

Comment: ya i have tried but getting error -- Error Error: Compile Error: expecting a colon, found '=' at line 5 column 151

Comment: actually what i am trying to do is like i m having two record types master & child in which i have to copy my master record types date to child record types by decreasing one day

Comment: ohh sorry dont give space between IN and : . like this `Master_Opportunity__c IN: op`

Comment: tried, bt now getting this -- Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Opportunity> at line 5 column 203

Comment: You need to change `op.Service_Start_Date__c - 1;` to `op[0].Service_Start_Date__c -1;` because op is a list.. In order to get records from list your need to use for loop or based on list index

Comment: You are quering Opportunity . assigning it to RecordType. Updating field on Record Type. direct accessing list. Check my answer and let me know if you face any issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fetch single record then do this

```
public class Close_Date_Updation
{
    public static void crUpdated(List<Opportunity> op)
    {  
      Map<Id, Opportunity> OppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(op);
      List <Opportunity> childRecord = [Select id,Revision_Date__c,Service_Start_Date__c,CloseDate,Master_Opportunity__c  from Opportunity where  RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Child_Opportunity' And Master_Opportunity__c =: op[0].id ];  //I hope Master_Opportunity__c  is Opportunity lookup
      for(Opportunity rt : childRecord){        
               opportunity opp = OppMap.get(rt.Master_Opportunity__c);
               rt.Service_Start_Date__c = Date.valueOf(opp.Service_Start_Date__c).adddays(-1);
               rt.Revision_Date__c = Date.valueOf(opp.Revision_Date__c).adddays(-1);  
               rt.CloseDate = Date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate).adddays(-1);
                   childRecord.add(rt);//I hope you are declaring this list

       }

        upsert childRecord; //insert will give error you are updating reocrd try upsert if you are not sure
   }

}
```

or if you want to fetch all records then do this.

```
public class Close_Date_Updation
    {
        public static void crUpdated(List<Opportunity> op)
        {  
          Map<Id, Opportunity> OppMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>(op);
          List <Opportunity> childRecord = [Select id,Revision_Date__c,Service_Start_Date__c,CloseDate from Opportunity where  RecordType.DeveloperName = 'Child_Opportunity' And Master_Opportunity__c IN: op];  //I hope Master_Opportunity__c  is Opportunity lookup
          for(Opportunity rt : childRecord){        

                   opportunity opp = OppMap.get(rt.Master_Opportunity__c);
                rt.Service_Start_Date__c = Date.valueOf(opp.Service_Start_Date__c).adddays(-1);
               rt.Revision_Date__c = Date.valueOf(opp.Revision_Date__c).adddays(-1);  
               rt.CloseDate = Date.valueOf(opp.CloseDate).adddays(-1);
                   childRecord.add(rt); //I hope you are declaring this list

           }

            upsert childRecord;
       }

    }
```

**Note:**  make sure field value is not null otherwise you will get null pointer exception.

Comment: Tushar so many error in Question like `op.Service_Start_Date__c - 1;` it should be like `op[0].Service_Start_Date__c - 1;` I think here a map is required OpId to op. Based on that we can get the corresponding opp value

Comment: @Ratan yes i have added them and updating code as i am finding new bugs in this code.

Comment: actually i have done some updation in my code , updated code is there actually i was trying to get list in record type list that was wrong, so now i am collecting in opportunity itself but now getting this error,,,  Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: List<Opportunity> at line 5 column 203

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM remove op.id from where condition just use `op`.

Comment: @Tushar i am getting this error in your updated code for single record-- Error: Compile Error: Type cannot be constructed: date at line 9 column 43

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM check my updated answer.

Comment: yah dude, i have tried but sorry to say still i m getting error-- Error: Compile Error: Initial term of field expression must be a concrete SObject: Map<Id,Opportunity> at line 10 column 57  in this line---- rt.Service_Start_Date__c = Date.valueOf(OppMap.Service_Start_Date__c).adddays(-1);

Comment: @RAVIGAUTAM check my updated answer.

Comment: @Tushar the code has no error now but when i am trying to updat the record trigger is giving unexpected error-----Error: Invalid Data. 
Review all error messages below to correct your data.
Apex trigger updater_Child_CD caused an unexpected exception, contact your administrator: updater_Child_CD: execution of AfterUpdate caused by: System.FinalException: Cannot modify a collection while it is being iterated.: Class.Close_Date_Updation.crUpdated: line 7, column 1